# How to generate test method for a singleton class instance in Vb.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, singleton, tdd

The following is my code and I am using the Test Project available in Visual Studio 2008

```
Public Class Calculator
    Public Shared objCalculator As Calculator = Nothing
    Private Sub New()

    End Sub
    Public Shared Function GetInstance() As Calculator
        If objCalculator Is Nothing Then
            objCalculator = New Calculator
        End If
        Return objCalculator
    End Function
End Class
```

Test Method

```
 '''<summary>
    '''A test for GetInstance
    '''</summary>
    <TestMethod()> _
    Public Sub GetInstanceTest()
        Dim expected As Calculator = Nothing
        Dim actual As Calculator
        actual = Calculator.GetInstance
        Assert.AreNotEqual(expected, actual)
        Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.")
    End Sub
```

Am I following the correct way to test the Singleton class.
I am using  **Assert.AreNotEqual(expected, actual)** this,

Answer (score 0):

While you are using `Assert.AreNotEqual()` correctly, the naming of `expected` is a bit strange. A better name is probably `notExpected`. Or just leave out the `expected` variable and pass in `Nothing` directly to `Assert.AreNotEqual()`.

Also, singletons are dangerous things. Your test will, when calling `GetInstance`, create a new `Calculator`. The next test that calls `GetInstance` will however not create a new `Calculator`, but reuse the one that the first test created. What you have done is that you have introduced a dependency between the tests. That's something you typically don't want to have. My advise is that you don't use singletons.